# Strange Javascript/JQuery behaviour when creating a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

```
    menuPaneToBe.title = document.createElement("div");
    $(menuPaneToBe).append(menuPaneToBe.title);
    console.log(1)
    console.log(menuPaneToBe.title)
    $(menuPaneToBe.title).addClass("menuTitle");
    console.log(2)
    $(menuPaneToBe.title).html("Title"); //Just placeholders, gets changed by circular-view
    console.log(3)
```

Console

```
1 MenuPane.js:12
[object HTMLDivElement] MenuPane.js:13
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLDivElement] jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
```

Why is the title just [object HTMLDivElement] instead of being a proper object? and why can't I set the class? MenuPaneToBe is a custom tag that is  set to display block.

```
<menu-pane id="menu"></menu-pane>

menu-pane {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: what is `menuPaneToBe`?

Comment: value of menuPaneToBe ? provide more code,provide html

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/K9UM8/1/

Comment: is `menuPaneToBe` a string or a jQuery object

Comment: there is no error in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/K9UM8/2/ - can edit it to recreate the problem.... also the browser used

Comment: also what is the result of `console.log(menuPaneToBe)`

Comment: instead of `menuPaneToBe.title` try changing it to `menuPaneToBe.somethingelse`

Comment: chrome. using the fiddle it says the title is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an strange issue, if `menuPaneToBe` is referring to a dom element(not jQuery object) then the title property will refer to the element's title property which is a string value. At least in Google Chrome when you assign a value to title of an element, it converts it to a string object.

So when you say `menuPaneToBe.title = document.createElement("div")`, it assigns the string value `[object HTMLDivElement]` to `menuPaneToBe.title`, which is an invalid jQuery selector.

Then when you say `$(menuPaneToBe.title)` it will throw the said error.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/K9UM8/3/)

Just change the property name from `title` to something else like `title2`

```
var menuPaneToBe = $('#menu')[0];
menuPaneToBe.title2 = document.createElement("div");
$(menuPaneToBe).append(menuPaneToBe.title2);
console.log(1)
console.log(menuPaneToBe.title2)
$(menuPaneToBe.title2).addClass("menuTitle");
console.log(2)
$(menuPaneToBe.title2).html("Title"); //Just placeholders, gets changed by circular-view
console.log(3)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/K9UM8/4/)